# React native App gets crashed on release mode with the following error null is not an object (evaluating 's.drawer._root')

Tags: android, react-native, native-base

I have used native base drawer which works fine in debug mode but when i created an release apk the app gets crashed with the following error.

```
AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: null is 
not an object (evaluating 's.drawer._root')
```

code:

```
 closeDrawer = () => {
 this.drawer._root && this.drawer._root.close();
};

openDrawer = () => {
this.drawer._root && this.drawer._root.open();
};

<Drawer
      ref={(ref) => {
        this.drawer = ref;
      }}
      type="overlay"
      side={'left'}
      openDrawerOffset={0.2}
      panOpenMask={0.2}
      tapToClose={true}
      content={
        <SideBar
          navigator={this.navigator}
          closeDrawer={() => this.closeDrawer()}
          {...this.props}
        />
      }
      tweenHandler={(ratio) => ({
        main: { opacity: (2 - ratio) / 2 }
      })}
      onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()}
    >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at the [react document](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#caveats-with-callback-refs) about ref

> If the ref callback is defined as an inline function, it will get called twice during updates, first with null and then again with the DOM element

in your closeDrawer  and openDrawer callback, this.drawer  might be null, maybe you should add some codes like

```
this.drawer && this.drawer._root && this.drawer._root.close();
this.drawer && this.drawer._root && this.drawer._root.open();
```